# Laravel - Get parameter from URI and receive database info based on that parameter

Tags: database, laravel, parameters

I'm working with laravel and I need to get a username from URL and then get info based on that from database, I don't have any idea as how to achieve this. Can someone help me out here?

```
Route::get('/profile/{username}', 'ProfileController@show');
```

And I have no idea how to call this in the controller and send it in the view, and then how to call things in the view.

```
public function show($username)
{
  User::where('username', $username)->get();
  return view('profile/index', ['username' => $username]);
}
```

How can I display stuff from that row in the view?

Thanks already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display data of that user try with the following code.

*projectname/app/Http/routes.php*

```
Route::get('/profile/{username}', 'ProfileController@show');
```

*projectname/app/Http/Controllers/ProfileController.php*

```
public function show($username)
{
    $user_data = User::where('username', $username)->first();
    return view('profile.index', ['username' => $username, 'user_data' => $user_data]);
}
```

*projectname/resources/views/profile/index.blade.php*

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
            <li>Username: {{ $username }}</li>
            <li>Name: {{ $user_data->name }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Please Note: I have assumed that `username` is unique; so I have used `first()` and you have `username`, `name` fields in table which is associated with User Modal.*

Above code is tested and working on Laravel 5.2. and on above given assumptions.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: It did, figured it out the original way tho, i got no clue of what was wrong anyways. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should read about [controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers) and [routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing). Your controller should look like this:

```
public function show($username)
{
    User::where('name', $usename)->get();
```

Here `$username` variable will contain `{username}` part from URI.

Comment: But how can i display stuff from that row on the page itself now then? Thanks for that first anwser tho

Comment: That is the correct answer. 

As for your other questions you should look through this videos, they explain it really really well and you will get started in notime.
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals

Comment: Cant find what i need in those videos :(